# Hiding all dropdowns in Foundation 4

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4 for a EmberJS + Cordova mobile app and I need to hide whatever dropdown is activated whenever I transition to a new view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'close', $('[data-dropdown-content]'));`

One could use any selector they want instead of `$('[data-dropdown-content'])` to select which dropdowns to hide.